# OpenCv 2.4.3 prebuild seems not to use TBB/IPP

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCv 2.4.3. I just downloaded it from their [site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/OpenCV-2.4.3.exe/download) and used the build that they have made. I did not want to take the headache of building it from the source myself. Anyway, in my machine the haar classifier gives very slow performance to detect faces. In another machine my friend runs it fine.( he built from source with TBB and IPP supprt on in cmake).

Though in the [release](http://opencv.org/opencv-2-4-3-released.html) they say that : **"You do not need TBB anymore on MacOSX, iOS and Windows. BTW, the binary package for Windows is now built without TBB support. Libraries and DLLs for Visual Studio 2010 use the Concurrency framework."**

I do not know much about these TBB and IPP. Only thing that I understand is making these things available will make multi-threading and parallelism possible resulting to speeding up my program.

Do I need to compile the source with cmake, TBB IPP bla bla... or there is something else that I am missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What they say, is that they have the pre-built binaries compiled in a way that does not need TBB, because they use another concurrency framework. So if You don't want to meddle in the library's settings You can use the pre-built version without sacrificing performance. But that is on Windows, iOS and MacOS.

The performance might also depend on the machines parameters (You know, cascades are power hungry), so if Your friend has a stronger machine, he will probably get better results, and OS You are operating, but I cannot tell You which is the best, as I didn't try OpenCV on anything besides Linux.

Comment: My friend's machine has lower configuration than the one I am currently working on. By the way, he is using Linux and I am Windows. To handle my current situation, I started implementing threading in my program with QThreads.